# Weighted piecewise regression to model proportion?

Tags: regression, logistic, sample-size, weighted-regression, piecewise-linear

I was trying to model the relationship between utilization of service (from 0 to 1) and travel distance. First I binned travel distance by each 20 km and then calculate utilization for each bin (count of people utilized service/total count of people in this bin). Hypothesis is that utilization would decrease as travel distance increases. However, since the population size is small for some bins that are far away, the calculated utilization is less "reliable" than those closer bins. For example, in the first graph, in some bins, there may be only 5 observations and they all utilized the service, resulting a utilization rate of 1.

I was wondering if I could exclude some bins with population size under a certain threshold and then conduct piecewise regression (as shown in the second graph). If so, what should be the appropriate threshold? Or if there's a way to assign more weights to the bins with larger size?
[image: graph1:all bins]
[image: graph2]

Thanks!
ybeybe

Comment: This hypothesis, natural though it is, is rarely correct, because it does not account for choices people make among competing alternatives. The locations at larger distances could very well be even *further* from alternatives. I have seen this happen in studying access to healthcare services: the rural areas tend to be far from everything. So, although your question can be answered with descriptions of how to weight the bins by population, I doubt that will produce the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks Whuber! you are right, those far locations are rural and they are far away from everything. In this case, the distance is between patients and the only service provider. so the only alternative is not getting treated.

Comment: Yes I agree that weighting probably won't produce the desired effect. I'll try fitting piecewise on the raw data (GLM piecewise). If the pattern does not follow the hypothesis, then we should respect what the data says.